# Hadoop, "Browse the filesystem" broken link on ec2

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I am newbie to setting hadoop on EC2. I am trying to set-up single node hadoop setup. I have successfully installed and ran Hadoop 1.1.2 on one of the Amazon EC2 instance. All nodes, namenode, datanode, jobtracker, mapred node are on the same machine.

My core-site cofiguration is

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

When I start the Hadoop, and go to web ui, namenode UI opens without any problem.

```
http://<namenode>:50070/dfshealth.jsp
```

But when clicked on the "Browse the filesystem", it redirects to

```
http://localhost:50075
```

which is incorrect. It should be something

```
http://<namenode>:50075.
```

But in this case it failes.

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using the fully qualified host names in your Hadoop configs, I've had issues when using **localhost** in the past. Namely, try setting the following (replace `$hostname` with yours):

In core-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://$hostname.ec2.demdex.com:9000</value>
</property>
```

In hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.http.address</name>
    <value>$hostname.ec2.demdex.com:50070</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>$hostname.ec2.demdex.com:50075</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I added the ec2 public dns name. Also followed [blog](http://codewut.de/content/bind-hadoop-specific-network-device). 

Now I am facing two problems. 
1. Broken links on Namenode Web UI.  
 If I add entries /etc/hosts some of them are resolved.
2. From java api I can am not able to upload file to hdfs.
50010 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 63000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect.