# Hadoop 2.2 on EC2 Web interface: "Browse the filesystem" and Datanode Links broken

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I have configured a single node cluster on Amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20140927 (ami-3d50120d)). Once I start the Hadoop cluster, I visit the NameNode web interface(http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:50070/dfshealth.jsp) which works fine.  But when navigating to the link that says "Browse the fileSystem" the link is broken and points to http://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?namenodeInfoPort=50070&dir=/&nnaddr=172.31.25.124:9000 - which is this instances private ip.  For this also occurs when visiting the datanode like under "Live nodes".
Somehow, these links are being resolved to the private ip address of my instance.  If I replace the url with the public dns of my instance these pages load correctly.  Has anyone seen and better yet solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully qualified host names in Hadoops configs. I think you need to change core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml to your public DNS names.

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894715/hadoop-browse-the-filesystem-broken-link-on-ec2)

Answer (score 0):

Use a socks proxy together with a proxy configuration tool. The instructions for EMR should work the same for an ec2 hadoop deployment.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-connect-master-node-proxy.html